# How to "Deactive" or switch back to an Excel Workbook

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a couple of Macros to generate other WorkBooks my main issue is this means I have to keep switching once the Excel WorkBook is created.
Is there a way to silently create a workbook or switch back to the original workbook once it's been created

Comment: Put your workbooks in variables and refer to the variables?

Comment: **Yes** there are ways and **no** you don't have to keep 'keep switching'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables to hold the workbooks and refer to them?

```
Public Sub SwitchWorkbooks()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\myFile.xlsx")

    wb2.Activate
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
    wb1.Activate
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

You can then refer simply using the variable without activating e.g

```
With wb1
    'do something with this workbook
End With

With wb2
    'do something with the other workbook
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it. You just need to store your workbooks in variables.

```
Public Sub Example()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add

    wb1.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1") = "this is workbook 1"

    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1") = "this is workbook 2"

End Sub
```